# Android project with multiple manifests

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I have an android studio project that has different folders being included depending on how the project is being built.

The file structure I am using looks like the following:

```
src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
        /java
        /res
src/FOO/AndroidManifest.xml
        /java
        /res
```

All of the configuration is done through gradle:

```
java.srcDirs += <src/FOO/java>
```

The issue is that I am not sure how to use the manifest that would be located in the FOO directory in addition to a main manifest.

Can this be done using manifest merging? Or is this not an intended usage?
Or does the manifest merger only look for manifests under directory the main manifest is located in?

I believe the manifest merger isn't aware of the manifest in src/FOO/AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 1):

The different paths that you describe should correspond to different build variants (flavour + build type combinations). In each build variant directory you can include a different AndroidManifest.xml file that will be merged with the one in the main folder. New (unknown) entries will simply be appended to the main AndroidManifest. The tricky part comes when you will have "conflicting" entries in the different folders. I would advise you to have a look at the documentation of the manifest merger, which can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge). It is pretty explanatory, and it also includes a link to the Android Studio's Merged Manifest view tool and how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think my problem is coming from the file structure I am using. Going to update my question with some more information

Comment: Remember that the manifest merger will be enabled for the corresponding Build Variant you are executing a build for.  Which also implies that you need to have properly configured your build.gradle to include the necessary product flavours (in this case the FOO product flavour)

Comment: my understanding is that only one flavor can be built at a time. Its not possible to build two flavors into one build is it?

Comment: Well you can build multiple flavours at a time (just provide the appropriate arguments in the Gradle command line). The manifest merger will have a look at the entries found in the flavour and build type (debug/release) and apply them to the main Android manifest. The resulting manifest will be used in output (eg apk).

Comment: If you can share a few more details, like build.gradle configuration and the AndroidManifest files that are not working, maybe we can figure this out